# Conditional Check based on another Tag

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an xml which has a structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XYZInquiry>
    <Source>ABC</Source>
    <Info>19991234</Info> 
<RawData>
        <EmailAddress>abc@email.com</EmailAddress>
</RawData>
</XYZInquiry>
```

and corresponding XSD for validation as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema id="XYZInquiry" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="XYZInquiry">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="Source" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="Info" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="RawData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
<xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="EmailAddress" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
```

I need to read Info Tag and based on the first 4 digits, I need to put condition on the RawData Tag. i.e. if The Info value starts with 1234, then RawData Tag is allowed else Invalid.
Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is [co-occurrence constraints](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_constraints).  This is possible in XSD 1.1 (not widely implemented) and [Scehmatron](http://www.schematron.com/).
It is not possible in Not possible in XSD 1.0